# Layout Items not appearing in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a simple Hacker News (https://news.ycombinator.com/) application that displays each article in a list view. I have successfully been able to retrieve the news and even populate a `Listview`, however, the listview is only being partially populated, as far as I can tell. My adapter list item looks like this: 
[image: Wanted Adapter] where the Title, time posted, user, points, number of comments, and domain are separate `Textview`s. however, when I run the application, I get this:
[image] 
So my question is, what is going wrong?

Here is my fragment for this listview:

```
package com.material.tdapps.hackernews.activity;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.JSON.JSONNewsParser;
import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.R;
import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.model.StoryFeed;
import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.model.StoryItem;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    StoryFeed storyFeed;
    Context context;
    ListView listView;
    NewsListAdapter newsListAdapter;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        context = this.getActivity();
        storyFeed = new StoryFeed();
        newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(this);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
        listView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);
        new AsyncLoadNewsFeed().execute();
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private class AsyncLoadNewsFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONNewsParser newsParser = new JSONNewsParser();
            storyFeed = newsParser.parseJSON("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json",0,30);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (storyFeed == null || storyFeed.getStoryCount() == 0){
                StoryItem nullStoryItem = new StoryItem();
                nullStoryItem.setTitle("ERROR: Null error!");
                nullStoryItem.setNumberComments(0);
                nullStoryItem.setScore(0);
                nullStoryItem.setBodyText("NULL");
                nullStoryItem.setTime(0);
                nullStoryItem.setAuthor("NULL");
                nullStoryItem.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
                storyFeed.addStory(nullStoryItem);
            }
            newsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class NewsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public NewsListAdapter(HomeFragment homeFragment){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) homeFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return storyFeed.getStoryCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        class listViewHolder {

            TextView titleTxtV;
            TextView timeTxtV;
            TextView scoreTxtV;
            TextView authorTxtV;
            TextView domTxtV;
            TextView comTxtV;

            ImageButton commB;

            listViewHolder(View v) {
                titleTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
                timeTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                scoreTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pointsText);
                authorTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.authorText);
                domTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.domainText);
                comTxtV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.commentsText);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View listItem = convertView;
            listViewHolder holder;

            if (listItem == null) {
                listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_layout, null);
                holder = new listViewHolder(listItem);
                listItem.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (listViewHolder) listItem.getTag();
            }

            holder.titleTxtV.setText(storyFeed.getStory(position).getTitle());
            holder.timeTxtV.setText("Posted " + storyFeed.getStory(position).getTime());
            holder.authorTxtV.setText("By " + storyFeed.getStory(position).getAuthor());
            holder.scoreTxtV.setText(storyFeed.getStory(position).getScore() + " Points");
            holder.comTxtV.setText(storyFeed.getStory(position).getNumberComments() + " Comments");
            try {
                holder.domTxtV.setText("(" + storyFeed.getStory(position).getURLDomain() + ")");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return listItem;

        }
    }

}
```

And my adapter item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="#ecf0f1"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_view_comments"
        android:background="#fff39c12"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="View Comments"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Pluto&apos;s Outer Moons Orbit Chaotically, With Unpredictable Sunrises and Sunsets"
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_above="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="1234 Points"
        android:id="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="1234 Comments"
        android:id="@+id/commentsText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pointsText"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="(gizmodo.com)"
        android:id="@+id/domainText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/commentsText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/commentsText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Posted 12 Hours Ago"
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="By user12345"
        android:id="@+id/authorText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/timeText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_layout, parent, false);`

You're currently setting your row's root elements to null, which will cause your layout_xx attributes to be ignored

http://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/